# How to update fragment's ui from another class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin in Android Studio. The app needs to get some JSON data over a websocket connection, convert it to a data class using gson and then pass it to a fragment to update a view element. I am trying to figure out the correct way to pass data between these classes properly. I need to update the Fragment's ui elements from the websocketClient class whitch is instanced in Mainactivity.

My project has these classes:
Mainacticity.kt, WebsocketClient.kt, Fragment1.kt dand DataClass.kt

I figured out, how to update UI from the WebsocketClient class by passing it 'this' as context and using context.runOnUiThread(), but it feels like the wrong way of doing it.

My initial idea of implementing fragment's ui updates from a class:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment(){
public fun onReceiveData(data : String){
    Toast.makeText(activity, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

class WebsocketClient(uri: URI, context: MainActivity): WebSocketClient(uri){
    override fun onMessage(message: String?) {
        Fragment1().onReceiveData(message)
    }
}
```

This gives me an error: android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: `Fragment1().` there is no reason to call methods on a Fragment you've just instantiated. Always add fragments to FragmentManager, then find them by their tag. In your case, find your Fragment by tag, then call the method on it.

Comment: I don't think i can run getsupportfragmentmanager() from my WebsocketClient class.

Comment: You probably just want to find an event bus like https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus so that you can communicate to all active observers without having a reference to them directly.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I got it working using EventBus. This makes everything so much easier. Thank You